# How to register mongodb with castle windsor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, castle-windsor

I am trying to insert an instance of MongoDatabase and don't know a good way to accomplish this.

I could try to wrap it in another object but that seems like a wasted abstraction since I do want to have direct access to the MongoDatabase object.

I was hoping that I would be able to create an object with then pass it to castle windsor and tell it to use that object when resolving.

Was hoping something like

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
var server = client.GetServer();
var database = server.GetDatabase("test");
```

Then I was hoping I could register with Windsor Castle the database object similiar to

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeOf(MongoDatabase)).UseTheCreatedObject(database));
```

Is it possible to do this or another way to get a `MongoDatabase` object setup?

The answer was what Krzysztof Koźmic suggested.  I was initially doing something like

```
Component.For(typeOf(MongoDatabase)).ImplementedBy<MongoDatabase>().Instance(database);
```

What this caused was an error that said MongoDatabase is already registered or implemented(can't remember).  So what I had to do was just remove the ImplementedBy.

Comment: You mean something like this? `.Instance(database)`

Comment: I will give this a try when I get a chance a tonight.  I think I tried this and got a strange error but will retry.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
Component.For<MongoDatabase>().Instance(database);
```